# Views attach block to a field

Tags: 7, views, taxonomy-terms

I want to create a simple websites listing. I have created a content type named `Sites` and a taxonomy vocab named `Sites` to handle `Sites` nodes categorization. i.e every Site node (a content of type Sites) belongs to one term under `Sites` taxonomy vocab.

In the Views module, I have created a new Page view which has the path `/sites-cats-listing` and it shows `Taxonomy terms` of type `Sites`. The format is `Unformatted list` and it is only has one field `Taxonomy term: Name`

It renders a simple list of Taxonomy vocab Sites terms as expected. However, I want to list all of sites titles that belongs to each taxonomy term, so, I will get two levels list something like the following example:

```
-term1
--Site1
--Site2
--Site3
-term2
--Site4
--SiteA
etc...
```

Also I need to be able to rewrite the site's title field to make it linked directly to the destination website.

So, I need to know is there any way to attach a block to field which the block takes its contextual filter from the field value? Or is there any other workaround to complete this task? I have tried [EVA](https://www.drupal.org/project/eva) but I could not able to find what I want to get.

Comment: When editing your view, look for the word SORT, next to it, click on add a field. Search for taxonomy term and click add. I think that should take care of your "Two level" list.

Answer (score 1):

this can be done with a bit of code in a tpl file or in a preprocess function.

Views has a function views_embed_view that you could use to embed the block into your field output.

```
print views_embed_view('views_name', 'display_id', $fieldvalue);
```

https://www.drupal.org/node/1336844